# Set a minimum order amount per vendor in Dokan

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

I want to have a minimum order amount in my Dokan store. The following code is doing the work but individual vendors can't select their own minimum value.

```
    //minimum order value

add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'required_min_cart_subtotal_amount' );
function required_min_cart_subtotal_amount() {


// Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

    // HERE Set minimum cart total amount
    $min_total = 200;


    // Total (before taxes and shipping charges)
    $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    // Add an error notice is cart total is less than the minimum required
    if( $total <= $min_total  ) {
        // Display an error message
        wc_add_notice( '<strong>' . sprintf( __("A minimum total purchase amount of %s is required to checkout."), wc_price($min_total) ) . '<strong>', 'error' );
         }
    }
}
```

So I added a custom field to the Dokan settings page

```
    //Extra field on the seller settings and show the value on the store banner -Dokan

// Add an extra field in seller settings

add_filter( 'dokan_settings_form_bottom', 'extra_fields', 10, 2);

function extra_fields( $current_user, $profile_info ){
$minimum_order= isset( $profile_info['minimum_order'] ) ? $profile_info['minimum_order'] : '';
?>
 <div class="gregcustom dokan-form-group">
    <label class="dokan-w3 dokan-control-label" for="setting_address">
        <?php _e( 'Minimum order value', 'dokan' ); ?>
    </label>
    <div class="dokan-w5">
        <input type="number" class="dokan-form-control input-md valid" name="minimum_order" id="reg_minimum_order" value="<?php echo $minimum_order; ?>" />
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}

//save the field value

add_action( 'dokan_store_profile_saved', 'save_extra_fields', 15 );
function save_extra_fields( $store_id ) {
$dokan_settings = dokan_get_store_info($store_id);
if ( isset( $_POST['minimum_order'] ) ) {
    $dokan_settings['minimum_order'] = $_POST['minimum_order'];
}
 update_user_meta( $store_id, 'dokan_profile_settings', $dokan_settings );
}
```

Now I want some code to use in here,

> $min_total = 200;

to get vendor id from items of the cart and use it to get user meta and to show that minimum_order value in above. (200)
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3):

Keep your extra field function and try to add this in your function.php. Just a little tricky but seems to work :)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'dokan_minimum_order_amount' );
function dokan_minimum_order_amount()
{

    $eachVendorCartTotal = array();
    $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    //build the array: [vendor_id][sub_total]
    foreach ($items as $item => $values) {

        $product_id = $values['product_id'];
        $product_qty = $values['quantity'];
        $product_price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'], '_price', true) * $product_qty;
        $vendor_id = get_post_field('post_author', $product_id);

        if (!array_key_exists($vendor_id, $eachVendorCartTotal)) {
            $eachVendorCartTotal[$vendor_id] = $product_price;
        } else {
            $sub_total = $product_price + $eachVendorCartTotal[$vendor_id];
            $eachVendorCartTotal[$vendor_id] = $sub_total;
        }

    }

    if (!empty($eachVendorCartTotal)) {
        foreach ($eachVendorCartTotal as $vendor_id => $value) {
            $errorMessage = "Your current order total for %s is %s — you must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order for this vendor";
            $store_info = dokan_get_store_info($vendor_id);
            $store_name = $store_info['store_name'];
            if(!empty($store_info['minimum_order'])) {
                $vendor_minimum = !empty($store_info['minimum_order']) ? $store_info['minimum_order'] : 0;
                if ($value < $vendor_minimum) {
                    if (is_cart()) {

                        wc_print_notice(
                            sprintf($errorMessage,
                                $store_name,
                                wc_price($value),
                                wc_price($vendor_minimum)
                            ), 'error'
                        );

                    } else {
                        wc_add_notice(
                            sprintf($errorMessage,
                                $store_name,
                                wc_price($value),
                                wc_price($vendor_minimum)
                            ), 'error'
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```